# Python script runs on PyCharm but not over python in console because of async

Tags: python, async-await, pycharm, python-asyncio, putty

Python chat bot does not run on puTTy console because of async although it works perfectly on PyCharm debug. 
I get the following error message in the puTTy console:

```py
async def ass(numb, message, update):
                ^
SyntaxError:
```

and this with following code (only important lines)

```py
async def ass(numb, message, update):
    if numb == 1:
        return get_value(message)
    if numb == 2:
        return get_value2(message)
    if numb == 3:
        return get_value1(message)
    else:
        return "error"


async def main():
    update_id = last_update(url)["update_id"]
    while (True):
        update = last_update(url)
        try:
            if update_id == update["update_id"]:

                message = get_message_text(update).lower()

                if message[:5] == "/dec ":
                    foo = await ass(1, message[5:], update)
                    send_message(get_chat_id(update), foo)
                elif message[:6] == "/decs ":
                    foo = await ass(2, message[6:], update)
                    send_message(get_chat_id(update), foo)
                elif message[:6] == "/dec3 ":
                    foo = await ass(3, message[6:], update)
                    send_message(get_chat_id(update), foo)

                requests.post(url + "getUpdates?offset=" + str(update_id))
                update_id += 1
                sleep(0.1)
                pass
        except:
            update_id += 1
            sleep(0.5)
            continue


asyncio.run(main())
```

Thank you!

Comment: What version of Python are you using inside PuTTY? `async` wasn't added until 3.5 so you'll get a `SyntaxError` in anything older than that.

Comment: How do I check my Python version or update my Python version?

Comment: How about removing the first async, and check if the error is raised in the second async.  By the way, you can use `python --version`.

Comment: The quickest way to check is to run `python -V` at a command prompt. There are many ways to install new versions, including installers available on python.org. Depending on what operating system you're using, you may also be able to install from its package manager.